# Upcoming events are not updating correctly

Tags: bug, dates, events

Recently we had a Moderators election 2023. I left the browser tab opened for a while and when I returned I saw that it said: "ends in 2 hours ago" which is wrong, there must be something like "ended 2 hours ago"

I think that is because the time updated automatically, but not the message. Maybe we must have a translation for past and future times or autoremove the event after the time ended.

What is interesting, after reloading the page, the event disappeared:

[image]

Comment: My guess: [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: The code which updates relative times while the page is displayed doesn't change any of the text surrounding the relative time. That text is handled in the backend. While this could be better, it's currently working as designed (i.e. you need to reload the page to have that text updated). However, such events are only rendered in the page until they end, so once the page is reloaded after the election ends, you won't see it.